# how can i display mysql results in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Good Evening all,
My name is eric, i am current learning how to build in flask using python , going ok at hte moment and connected to the database, i can search with no issues, i have two issues i am hoping you can please help me with

1. in my query it has to be the 100% correct word i would like it to be close to the word incase of caps or miss spelling
2. how do i display the results on the screen all i can get at the moment is found results or no results

Thank you in advance

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def Authenticate():
    search = request.form['si']
    cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * from Companys where B_Type='" + search + "'")
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    if data is None:
        return "Could not find the data you are looking for"
    else:
        return "Found Data"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 
return render_template('filename.html',data=data)

and can use jinja2 to render it on HTML like this:
{{ data }}

or follow [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) link